# Header files not found by 'make'

Tags: makefile, compiler-errors, mpi, petsc

The `make` instruction is not finding the libraries required for compilation. They are in other folder than the usual `/usr/include` folder.

I'm complying a simulation software called magnum.fe I already installed all the required dependencies (FEniCS = 1.5
CMake >= 2.8
SWIG >= 2.0
G++ >= 4.0) and started to run `make` as the instructions suggest.

```
$ cd /path/to/magnum.fe
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake ..
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

But when running make I get the following error:

```
/usr/include/petscsys.h:136:12: fatal error: petsc/mpiuni/mpi.h: No such file or directory
  136 | #  include <petsc/mpiuni/mpi.h>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

The files do exist, but in other folder: `/home/myusername/bin/petsc/include/mpiuni/mpi.h`

I compiled `petsc` on `/home/myusername/bin/petsc/` with the following instruction:

```
$ ./configure --with-cc=gcc --with-cxx=g++ --with-fc=gfortran --download-mpich --download-fblaslapack
$ make all check
```

It compiled it sucessfully but I couldn't get the magnum.fe compilation to finish.

I tried moving each header file to `/usr/include` but now I'm stuck on if moving the whole petsc directory into this folder. It must be a more elegant way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: I found out thet I can specify the libraries to be used in the make file with the `LDLIBS` line. But I couldn't do it so I copied the entire ...petsc/include folder to /usr/include and worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made it!

There are two options available:

**Specify the libraries** to use with the make command editing the MAKEfile, use the variable `LDLIBS` to set it up. Detailed usage in here: [https://web.archive.org/web/20070723140628/http://arco.inf-cr.uclm.es/~david.villa/doc/repo/make/make.html#AEN36](https://web.archive.org/web/20070723140628/http://arco.inf-cr.uclm.es/%7Edavid.villa/doc/repo/make/make.html#AEN36)

or

**Create symbolic links** pointing to `/usr/include`. In my case I used:

```
ln -s /home/myusername/bin/petsc/include/* /usr/include
```